# Sync Task's Overwrite Attribute Copies Identical Files

Tags: ant

I've come across an issue with Ant's `Sync` task where files are being copied unnecessarily.  The goal is to update everything in the `${destination}` directory with the contents of the `${source}` directory, even if the file in the `${destination}` is newer.  Based on Ant's [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sync.html), I've added an `overwrite` attribute to to ensure the `${destination}` is overwritten.

```
<target name="test">
    <sync todir="${destination}" overwrite="true" granularity="5000">
        <fileset dir="${source}">
        </fileset>
    </sync>
</target>
```

This task correctly overwrites the `${destination}`, but the file is always copied, even when the source and destination are identical.  This leads to a lot of unnecessary traffic.

Based on the documentation, I attempted to configure the `granularity` attribute, but this doesn't appear to have any effect.  I'm also running this test between two directories on the same machine, so I wouldn't expect timestamp differences (certainly not of more than 5 seconds).

Any thoughts about why the `Sync` task and `overwrite` attribute function in this way?  Are there any solutions using the default set of Ant tasks to prevent the unnecessary file copying?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the sync task with overwrite="true", you will get this behavior.

You could use it with overwrite="false", and then follow up with a [copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) that only copy the files that are existing but different, with the [different selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#differentselect), e.g.:

```
<copy  todir="${destination}">
    <fileset dir="${source}">
        <different targetdir="${destination}" ignoreFileTimes="true"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```